# My computer doesn't turn on? Bad motherboard?

Tags: post

I have an Asus P8Z68-v LX motherboard, an Intel i5-2500K CPU, and a Corsair CX600 PSU hooked up for a test boot.  However, when I short the 2 power pins on the motherboard, nothing happens.  No fans turn on, no beep, nothing.  There's a green LED that's lit on the motherboard, though.  I know for sure that the PSU isn't the problem because for 1, it's a good brand, and 2, I tried another PSU.  I have the 24 pin power connector and the 8 pin connector plugged in to the appropriate spots on the motherboard.  I also have the CPU fan plugged in.

So, is it the motherboard that's bad?  Do I need to get it exchanged for another one?

Comment: It sounds like the motherboard is DOA.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you are shorting the right two pins. Make sure the clear CMOS jumper is in the normal position. Make sure the CPU is properly mounted. Make sure the motherboard isn't shorting against the case or anything else.

Comment: I tried all of that.  No luck.

Comment: It turns out for whatever reason I have to short ALL the pins...  Weird, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You suggest that you have tested this questionable PSU on another computer and it turns on fine?
Just a few couple ball ideas...
-Maybe the PSU doesn't provide enough power to boot your computer?
-Computer isn't POSTING for some hardware related reason? (although there should be some sort of diagnostic beeping or flashing lights)
-It could be the motherboard if you know the CPU, PSU, and PSU supply are fine/adequate

Comment: The PSU is 600 Watts, which should be more than enough to power just the CPU and mobo.  There isn't any POST or any kind of response for that matter.